# F# enum: expected to have type xxx but here has type xxx

Tags: enums, f#

I'm trying to use LightningDB.net. One of the methods accepts arguments as enum flags.

Method declaration in C#:

```
Open(EnvironmentOpenFlags openFlags = EnvironmentOpenFlags.None, UnixAccessMode accessMode = UnixAccessMode.Default)
```

When I provide an argument for `openFlags` such as: `env.Open(EnvironmentOpenFlags.NoSync)` I'm getting compiler error:

```
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type    LightningDB.EnvironmentOpenFlags    but here has type    LightningDB.EnvironmentOpenFlags
```

When I provide argument for 2nd argument of the method, it works:

```
env.Open(accessMode = UnixAccessMode.Default)
```

Any combination, including trying to convert enum to int and then back always result in compiler error.

This is on VS 2015. Any idea what might be causing this and how to work around?

Comment: I would check you are not somehow referencing two different versions of the same dll

Comment: I don't seem I do, besides, if that would've been the case, the error would've appeared with the 2nd argument, which is also of enum flags type, right?

Comment: But maybe the second Arg is from a different dll

Comment: Actually that was weird, a different assembly was causing this, even though I didn't open namespace from it. I think it embedded the original LightningDB.net assembly. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assembly was in the project once, once directly referenced and second time embedded inside another assembly, thus leading to the error.